# TikZ: using decorations.markings to decorate a clipped path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I clipped a circle along the line `atan(2/3)`.  Where the circle is clipped I would like to put an arrow.  I thought it would be as simple as `(atan(2/3) + 180)/360` to get its percentage location along the path.  Unfortunately, it wasn't.  I ended up subtracting `32.5` degrees due to trial and error.  I would like to make a more exact placement though.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{atan(2/3)};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ppi}{\angle + 180};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\percent}{(\ppi - 32.5)/360};

  \begin{scope}[rotate = \angle, decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position \percent with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }]
    \clip (0, .4) rectangle (-.45, 0);

    \draw[postaction = decorate] (cylinder) circle[radius = .395cm];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us analyse. Without `\clip`,without rotation and the drawn rectangle this is your circle:

[image]

This shows that the `\percent` value should be `50`. With

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ppi}{\angle + 180};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\percent}{(\ppi)/360};
```

You are certainly not giving `50%` but more than that. To be exact, you are giving `atan(2/3)` more to `\ppi`. If we make `\ppi` = 180, then `\percent` will be `50`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{atan(2/3)};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ppi}{180};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\percent}{(\ppi)/360};

  \begin{scope}[rotate = 0, decoration = {%     % change rotate to \angle
      markings,
      mark = at position \percent with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }]
    %\clip (0, .4) rectangle (-.45, 0);
    \draw (0, .4) rectangle (-.45, 0);

    \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle[radius = .395cm];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can rotate and clip to get:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{atan(2/3)};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ppi}{180};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\percent}{(\ppi)/360};

  \begin{scope}[rotate = \angle, decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position \percent with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }]
    \clip (0, .4) rectangle (-.45, 0);
    %\draw (0, .4) rectangle (-.45, 0);

    \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle[radius = .395cm];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]